# Return of getContentType() in mocked HttpServletResponse instance is null

Tags: java, mockito

When I try to judge the return value of `response.getContenttype()`, the Run console display:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :text/plain
Actual   :null
```

But when I try to judge the return value of `stringWriter()`, it is ok:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Source code:

Business code snippet:

Set content type:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    process(request, response);
}
```

Write printWriter:

```
@Override
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
    ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject resultObject = queryMXRatioData(request);
    response.getWriter().write(resultObject.toJSONString());
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestServlet extends Mockito {
private HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
private HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
private HttpSession session = mock(HttpSession.class);
private StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
private PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    when(request.getParameter("start")).thenReturn("0");
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(printWriter);
}

@Test
public void testGetContentType() throws Exception {
    new MXRatioDataLoader().doPost(request, response);

    assertEquals("text/plain", response.getContentType());
}

@Test
public void testStringWriter() throws Exception {
    new MXRatioDataLoader().doPost(request, response);
    String expect = "{\"total\":1,\"data\":[{\"U\":\"230.36575\",\"LOWLIMIT\":\"200\",\"OID\":\"5629499552628739\",\"NAME\":\"220kV\",\"RATIO\":\"104.7%\",\"LIMIT\":\"250\"}]}";
    assertEquals(expect, stringWriter.toString());
}
```

Comment: There's no need to have the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation. That is for automatically creating mocks annotated with `@Mock` whereas you are creating yours manually

Comment: @Phil, you are right, i will change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `HttpServletResponse` is mocked, the code that calls

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

is a no-op; the mock has no state and doesn't do anything with the *set* call other than record that it happened.

A better test would be to *verify* the appropriate call was made, ie

```
new MXRatioDataLoader().doPost(request, response);
verify(response).setContentType("text/plain");
```